# Format rjson output for human readability?

Tags: r, rjson

I use the following rjson code to create a JSON file, where df represents my input dataframe.

`result <- toJSON(list(items=lapply(1:nrow(df),function(i)df[i,])))`

The file appears as:

`{"items":[{"name":"Item 1","group":1},{"name":"Item 2","group":1},{"name":"Item 3","group":2}]}`

However, I would like to make the output more human-readable, as in:

```
{
 "items":[
   {"name":"Item 1","group":1},
   {"name":"Item 2","group":1},
   {"name":"Item 3","group":2}
 ]
}
```

RJSONIO has as the "pretty" option but does not create the JSON format that I required by my application.  Is there a way to create the output file I am looking for using rjson, other than post-processing the file itself?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: can you include a `dput(df)`? There may be a way to bend rjsonlite to your will (i.e. make it output what you need) and it has a pretty print option.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're set on `RJSONIO` (I find it a bit confusing at times).  But since you mention `rjson`, then perhaps you're also open to using another json package.  Here's a possibility that uses the `jsonlite` package.

```
# unloadNamespace(RJSONIO) ## to avoid confusion between packages
library(jsonlite)

x <- '{"items":[{"name":"Item 1","group":1},{"name":"Item 2","group":1},{"name":"Item 3","group":2}]}'

## to go back and create your example list of 1 data frame
( dfl <- fromJSON(x) )
# $items
#     name group
# 1 Item 1     1
# 2 Item 2     1
# 3 Item 3     2

## prettify your json output
toJSON(dfl, pretty = TRUE)
```

which returns the following pretty json that can be saved to file with `writeLines()`

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Item 1",
            "group": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Item 2",
            "group": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Item 3",
            "group": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not wedded to JSONIO.  I was able to adapt your code suggestion to a nested list and my application reads the resulting JSON file perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`rjson::toJSON` (now?) has `indent=0` option.  Give it a non-zero value and use writeLines.  No other package needed.